# Creating rows in a SELECT based on INT from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

Lets say I have a table called 'contracts' which has a column 'NumYears'.

eg.

```
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    NumYears
FROM Contracts

ClientId NumYears
-------- -----------
123456789    5
987654321    3
```

I have another table 'contract_reviews' which can JOIN onto contracts via the ClientId.

every year the user is requested to review the information held on file and upon completion inserts a new row into 'contract_reviews'

```
SELECT
    ClientId,
    Reviewed,
    YearFor,
    OtherColumn
FROM Contract_Reviews

ClientId  Reviewed    YearFor OtherColumn
--------- ----------- ------- -----------
123456789 1           2018    '£100'
123456789 1           2019    '£100'
```

Client '123456789' may be in the second year, so 'contract_reviews' will only hold 2 records. By the end of the 'NumYears' we should expect 5.

Basically, I need to select all rows from 'contract_reviews' and generate new empty rows for the missing 'contract_reviews' up to the count of 'NumYears'

```
ClientId  Reviewed    YearFor OtherColumn
--------- ----------- ------- -----------
123456789 1           2018    '£100'
123456789 1           2019    '£100'
123456789 0           NULL    NULL
123456789 0           NULL    NULL
123456789 0           NULL    NULL
```

This question [Duplicated rows (x) amount of times in a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170824/duplicated-rows-x-amount-of-times-in-a-table) offered some help but the solution is still evading me.

Comment: What if there are no rows yet in table the review table for a given contract?

Comment: Great question! I hadn't considered that, thanks. I think for reporting purposes it should return X (NumYears) of blank rows because if there are no records that is a failure on our part as the first record should be inserted when the contract was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        c.clientId, 
        c.numYears - (
            select count(*) from contract_reviews cr where cr.clientId = c.clientId
        ) numYears
    from contracts c
    union all
    select clientId, numYears - 1 from cte where numYears > 1
)
insert into contract_reviews(clientId) 
select clientId from cte
```

The anchor of the recursive cte computes how many rows are "missing" in the review table for each customer, then the recursive part generates them. Finally, the outer query does the inserts.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57280c7d5ffc2bf4ed6cbf5e8e621aa2)** - once the query is executed, the content of the review table is:

```
ClientId  | Reviewed | YearFor | OtherColumn
:-------- | :------- | :------ | :----------
123456789 | 1        | 2018    | £100      
123456789 | 1        | 2019    | £100      
123456789 | null     | null    | null       
123456789 | null     | null    | null       
123456789 | null     | null    | null       
987654321 | null     | null    | null       
987654321 | null     | null    | null       
987654321 | null     | null    | null
```